# Tree shaking doesn't work with webpack 4 and semantic-ui-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui

I'm importing only one component from semantic-ui-react

```
import { Button as SemanticButton} from 'semantic-ui-react';
```

but after running `webpack -p` I see all the components from Semantic UI in the bundle and its size is over 300KB (~30KB without Semantic UI).
I installed all the latest versions: webpack@4.14.0; semantic-ui-react@0.81.3

Here's my webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./'),
      'node_modules',
    ],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.less'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs: 'react',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      amd: 'React',
    },
    'react-dom': {
      root: 'ReactDOM',
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'ReactDOM',
    },
    'prop-types': {
      root: 'PropTypes',
      commonjs: 'prop-types',
      commonjs2: 'prop-types',
      amd: 'PropTypes',
    },
  },
};
```

Am I doing something wrong? How do I make tree shaking work with semantic-ui-react? I don't want to see the unused components in the bundle.

Comment: Are the unused components from SemanticUI still there if you add `mode: "production"` to your Webpack configuration for production?

Comment: Yes because `webpack -p` runs webpack in production mode. I also tried `mode: "production"` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem turned to be fairly simple. You just need to configure Babel correctly.

> Simply specifying `"modules": false` in your babel-preset-env config gets Babel to behave how we want, which allows webpack to analyze your dependency tree and shake off those unused dependencies. Furthermore, this process doesn't cause compatibility issues, as webpack ends up converting your code into a format that's widely compatible, anyway.

So `.babelrc` can look like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-javascript/tree-shaking/)

Comment: you should accept this as the answer if it satisfies your question perhaps